# Spring's Alternative To Apache Commons Config

Tags: spring

I use Apache commons config very often, and its a great library .

I wander what's springs solution to handling property files.

I have seen a few DataSource JDBC config examples, and I want to know more.

hope it has set of great features the commons offers, such as variable substitution etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a quick introduction, check [Spring 3.1 M1: Unified Property Management](http://spring.io/blog/2011/02/15/spring-3-1-m1-unified-property-management/). From the summary:

> **Summary**
>
> Spring's Environment abstraction provides a single location to configure both profiles and properties. Profiles, as described in earlier posts, determine which bean definitions should be registered for a given deployment context; the property support described in this post provides a consistent abstraction over any source of properties, resulting in more flexible property access and placeholder resolution throughout your application configuration.